# Download a file through ASP.Net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, download

I'm pushing a PEM file towards my website user for download. here is the code:

```
try
{
    FileStream sourceFile = null;

    Response.ContentType = "application/text";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(RequestFilePath));
    sourceFile = new FileStream(RequestFilePath, FileMode.Open);
    long FileSize = sourceFile.Length;
    byte[] getContent = new byte[(int)FileSize];
    sourceFile.Read(getContent, 0, (int)sourceFile.Length);
    sourceFile.Close();
    Response.BinaryWrite(getContent);
}
catch (Exception exp)
{
    throw new Exception("File save error! Message:<br />" + exp.Message, exp);
}
```

The issue is that the file that is downloaded has the content that should be there + a copy of the whole web page's HTML too.

Whats happening here?

Comment: Where is that code executing? In an HTTP handler, in a button click?

Comment: before setting response first clear it.

Comment: @HassanGulzar - +1 for your code. that helped me a lot. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line:

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ContentType = "application/text";
...
```

Comment: Still the whole page get written.

Comment: Add Response.End() at the end

Comment: That fixed it. Its now between `Response.ClearContent()` and 
`Response.ContentType = "application/text"`

Comment: I do notice that an exception is generated after `Response.End()'. But the exception is undefined. It reads: `ThreadAbortException`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Place the following...

```
Response.Clear();
```

Before...

```
Response.ContentType = "application/text";
```

**Update**

As @Amiram says in his comments (and I was about to add myself anyway)...

After...

```
Response.BinaryWrite(getContent);
```

Add...

```
Response.End();
```

Comment: Still the whole page get written.

Comment: @Hassan, do you mean that the whole page (as well as the contents of the file you are downloading) are being combined into the file being downloaded?

Comment: Yup, they were. First was the actual data I wanted followed by the rendered HTML of the whole page. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [@Amiram Korach's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11434245/1369235).
That is add `Response.ClearContent();` before `Response.ContentType...`

But as per [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434164/download-a-file-through-asp-net-website#comment15085065_11434245)

> Still the whole page get written

[@Amiram Korach replied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434164/download-a-file-through-asp-net-website#comment15085087_11434245) to add `Response.End()` at the end.
But it throws `System.Threading.ThreadAbortException`.

So I advice you to add additional `catch` to catch `System.Threading.ThreadAbortException` and don't put error message in `Response.Write` otherwise it will also be added to your text file:

```
try
{
    FileStream sourceFile = null;
    Response.ClearContent(); // <<<---- Add this before `ContentType`.
    Response.ContentType = "application/text";
    .
    .
    Response.BinaryWrite(getContent);
    Response.End(); // <<<---- Add this at the end.
}
catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException) //<<-- Add this catch.
{
    //Don't add anything here.
    //because if you write here in Response.Write,
    //that text also will be added to your text file.
}
catch (Exception exp)
{
    throw new Exception("File save error! Message:<br />" + exp.Message, exp);
}
```

This will solve your problem.